# Ive a function in Kotlin and trying to use it Android Studio, but it doesnt work

Tags: android, function, kotlin

**If I click the button1 the function has to change the text.**
The text is here:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**And I want to change the Text "Hello World" to a text from my function :**

```
    fun aufruf() {
        val items = mutableListOf<BisHunterMarksman>()
        items.add(BisHunterMarksman("Head", "Rattling Deadeye Hood\t", "\tThe Necrotic Wake"))
        items.add(BisHunterMarksman("Necklace", "Trailspinner Pendant\t", "\tMists of Tirna Scithe"))
    for (element in items) {
            println("${element.itemSlot}\t" + element.name + element.itemsource)
        }
    }
```

This have to print the text from fun aufruf

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            val button1 = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
            val myTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
    
    
      

  button1.setOnClickListener(){
    
    

                val myText = aufruf()
                    myTextView.text = "$myText"
        }
    }
```

Comment: `aufruf` doesn't return a string, it just prints it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
fun aufruf(): String {
    val items = mutableListOf<BisHunterMarksman>()
    items.add(BisHunterMarksman("Head", "Rattling Deadeye Hood\t", "\tThe Necrotic Wake"))
    items.add(BisHunterMarksman("Necklace", "Trailspinner Pendant\t", "\tMists of Tirna Scithe"))

    var myText = ""
    items.forEach {
        myText = "$myText${it.itemSlot}\t${it.name}${it.itemSource}"
    }
    return myText
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
        val button1 = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
        val myTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
    
        button1.setOnClickListener(){
            val myText = aufruf()
            myTextView.text = myText
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Now if Im trying this, element is then unresolved

Comment: @ProAslan Sorry. My fault. I edited the comment already. please check again.

Comment: Ah ok I must just use google sometimes xD

Comment: @ProAslan 
Yeah. And if my answer helps you to solve your problem, I hope you can accept my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok now I can do it like this with "it" :

```
     var myText = ""
     items.forEach {
         myText = "$myText${it.itemSlot}\t${it.name}"
     }
     return myText
 }
```